# 'void Transport::signal()' is protected

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, сигналы-слоты

Ошибка:

```
//transport.cpp:67: error: 'muttrc_switch' was not declared in this scope
            emit muttrc_switch();
                               ^

class Transport : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit Transport(QObject *parent = 0);
  QString transport(QString, QString);
signals:
  void muttrc_switch ();
};
Transport::Transport(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{}

QString transport(QString email, QString file)
{
  ConfigMuttrc mutrc;
  Transport mutrc_s;
  QObject::connect(&mutrc_s, SIGNAL (muttrc_switch ()), &mutrc, SLOT (muttrc_config ()));
  emit mutrc_s.muttrc_switch();
}
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Неправильная сигнатура функции `transport`: `QString Transport::transport(QString email, QString file)`

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Офирмите пожалуйста в виде ответа, я зачту.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Забыли указать область видимости класса в сигнатуре функции:

```
QString Transport::transport(QString email, QString file)
```